Out of Memory when trying to load an image into an pictureBox C#
I am experiencing an issue when trying to load an image into a pictureBox component.
I tried monving it to a smaller progrom to test but I still get the same issue.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace TryCardAgain
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void setImage() {

            pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"fullPathToImage\bin\x64\Debug\assets\Character_Acheron_Icon.png");

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setImage();
        }
    }
}

Tried loading a picture into a picture box, but I get out of memory issue.
ee the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at TryCardAgain.Form1.setImage() in C:\Users\sandr\source\repos\TryCardAgain\TryCardAgain\Form1.cs:line 32
   at TryCardAgain.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\sandr\source\repos\TryCardAgain\TryCardAgain\Form1.cs:line 40
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9256.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
TryCardAgain
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/sandr/source/repos/TryCardAgain/TryCardAgain/bin/x64/Debug/TryCardAgain.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9251.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9251.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9241.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.



Here is my stacktrace. Although it seems like C# just doesn't like the actual images.

What is the size of the Character_Acheron_Icon.png file, please?


also verify whether that is actually a PNG image and not something else with the .png extension


The image is ~16KB, and is a png.

The folder has a total of ~50 images. The folder as a whole is less than a MB.

The file size is irrelevant. What matters is the dimension of the image (width x height) -- How did you verify that it's a PNG image? How was it created? What is the pixel format?

The image is 160x160. Images properties says PNG(.png). It was ordinally the WEB(?) file type, I saved it by changing file type to All files, and saying .png at the end of it.

Can you  post the full stack trace?

My laptop killed itself, and I don't have any place to currently charge it. But What I can say is that when I try to set the image directly in the GUI builder, I get some kind of error of it not being a valid resource.

@Charlieface, I'll post the stack trace when I get a chance. Is there a specific format that I need to post it in?

GDI+ throws out of memory exceptions all the time for no reason, including when the file is corrupt.

No just enclose in three backticks ``` on the line before and after. [edit] into your post, not as a comment.

Just renaming the file won't change the contents. It's likely still encoded in the WEB(?) format while the code is attempting to read it as PNG

I saved it by changing file type to All files, and saying .png at the end of it ouch!

@TaW Never had an issue with it before. xD

Well, both Jonathan and your self-answered post describe how to do it: Export as a different type, not just change the extension!

It was a simple error. The images themselves seemed to be the issue. When I threw an image into an editor, then exported it again as a png, it worked.
